# Python Variable in an HTML email in Python

Tags: python, email, html-email, smtplib

How do I insert a variable into an HTML email I'm sending with python? The variable I'm trying to send is `code`. Below is what I have so far.

```
text = "We Says Thanks!"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for being a loyal customer.<br>
       Here is your unique code to unlock exclusive content:<br>
       <br><br><h1><% print code %></h1><br>
       <img src="http://example.com/footer.jpg">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: for more complex cases you might need a template engine such as [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [`"formatstring".format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
code = "We Says Thanks!"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for being a loyal customer.<br>
       Here is your unique code to unlock exclusive content:<br>
       <br><br><h1>{code}</h1><br>
       <img src="http://example.com/footer.jpg">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(code=code)
```

If you find yourself substituting a large number of variables, you can use

```
.format(**locals())
```

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to use [Templates](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings):

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> html = '''\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for being a loyal customer.<br>
       Here is your unique code to unlock exclusive content:<br>
       <br><br><h1>$code</h1><br>
       <img src="http://example.com/footer.jpg">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
'''
>>> s = Template(html).safe_substitute(code="We Says Thanks!")
>>> print(s)
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for being a loyal customer.<br>
       Here is your unique code to unlock exclusive content:<br>
       <br><br><h1>We Says Thanks!</h1><br>
       <img src="http://example.com/footer.jpg">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note, that I used `safe_substitute`, not `substitute`, as if there is a placeholder which is not in the dictionary provided, `substitute` will raise `ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string`. The same problem is with [`string formatting`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting).

Comment: If we have multiple variables need to be replaced in single html , how can we provide ?

Answer (score 2):

use pythons string manipulation:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

generally the % operator is used to put a variable into a string, %i for integers, %s for strings and %f for floats, 
NB: there is also another formatting type (.format) which is also described in the above link, that allows you to pass in a dict or list slightly more elegant than what I show below, this may be what you should go for in the long run as the % operator gets confusing if you have 100 variables you want to put into a string, though the use of dicts (my last example) kinda negates this.

```
code_str = "super duper heading"
html = "<h1>%s</h1>" % code_str
# <h1>super duper heading</h1>
code_nr = 42
html = "<h1>%i</h1>" % code_nr
# <h1>42</h1>

html = "<h1>%s %i</h1>" % (code_str, code_nr)
# <h1>super duper heading 42</h1>

html = "%(my_str)s %(my_nr)d" %  {"my_str": code_str, "my_nr": code_nr}
# <h1>super duper heading 42</h1>
```

this is very basic and only work with primitive types, if you want to be able to store dicts, lists and possible objects I suggest you use cobvert them to jsons http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759634/python-json-tutorial are good sources of inspiration

Hope this helps